# update and regenerate thumbnails for wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite, wpmu

For my multisite installations (with over 1500 sites on one of them) I am looking for the most efficient way to change the thumbnailsite to 300x300. On a single site you can easily do this by changing the mediasettings and then running the regenerate thumbnails plugin. I don't want to do this manually for all the sites so I'm thinking about how to do this by code.

To set the thumbnailsize is a part which I can figure out. I'll just make a loop that loops through all the sites in the network and use the code to update the default thumbnailsettings:

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); set_post_thumbnail_size( 300, 300, true ); // default thumbnail size 
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do the regenerating since I can't really find advice on how to code this. When I search for this I just find developers recommending the regenerate thumbnails plugin. Also with the code I'm a little bit skeptical it'll become too heavy for my wpmu.

Is there something code/plugin that can do what I want ? (regenerate thumbnails for the whole network ?)

Comment: There is a plugin called [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

Comment: are you using WPL CLI yet? The [Media Regenerate](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/regenerate/) command line should simplify your task.

Comment: @caduDeCastroAlves This is a joke right ?

Comment: @gael Thank you very much, I think the wp cli can be accecces, I'm gonna take a look at it and will get back on if it worked

Comment: @Maartje I'm sorry but I read "1500 sites" as "1500 images". I might need more coffee

Comment: @cadudecastroalves haha that would've been easier yeah :)

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves, that is a great plugin for single site installations, indeed.
Unfortunately not so much for MultiSite, because all thumbnails for the sub blogs will also be put the Media Library of the main blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `wp cli` on the command line you can use the [Media regenerate](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/regenerate/) command line for every website:

```
wp media regenerate -url=https://sub1.example.com 

wp media regenerate -url=https://sub2.example.com
```

Then for a large number of sites you can use a loop which could look like that:

```
for i in sub1.example.com sub2.example.com sub3.example.com
do wp media regenerate -url=https://$i --yes
done
```

For each website in the list `i`, the command line regenerates medias.

I added the `--yes` option to Answer yes to the confirmation message.

Comment: Do I need to enter all the sites or is it possible to make some sort of loop?

Comment: I edited my answer with a loop example. Tell me if you want more precisions

Comment: Thanks! ill get back on this soon

Answer (score 0):

as per https://danielbachhuber.com/tip/run-wp-cli-command-wordpress-multisite/

you can do a full loop bash ( also it is --url instead of -url )

this results in

```
wp site list --field=url | xargs -n1 -I % wp --url=% media regenerate --yes
```